# Cannot find contract attachments

Tags: java, corda

I tried to launch my Cordapp from IDE. When I make request I get following error:

> net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find
>   contract attachments for [com.example.contract.IBuildContract].

I read about this problem here: https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging

But IDE can find `setExtraCordappPackagesToScan`. How I can set extra packages or save this problem in other way in corda v3?

Answer (score 1):

Do not add the Contract name .I mean just include till the package .

**withExtraCordappPackagesToScan(Arrays.asList("com.example.contract")**

In java , we are including the package as below :

@Before
    public void setup() {
        network = new MockNetwork(ImmutableList.of("com.xyz.module1.contract","com.xyz.module2.contract"));

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the node driver to start your nodes, here's an example of setting the extra CorDapp packages to scan:

```
driver(DriverParameters(
    isDebug = true, 
    extraCordappPackagesToScan = listOf("net.corda.vega.contracts", "net.corda.vega.plugin.customserializers"))
) {
    TODO("Driver logic.")
}
```

Comment: I can't do like this in java. 
I try this code 
`driver(
                new DriverParameters().
                       withIsDebug(true).
                       withWaitForAllNodesToFinish(true).
                       withExtraCordappPackagesToScan(Arrays.asList("com.example.contract.IBuildContract"))`
but result the same
P.S Contract code
`package com.example.contract;
public class IBuildContract implements Contract {
    public static final String IBUILD_CONTRACT_ID = "com.example.contract.IBuildContract";
`

Comment: It's very strange on linux the same program work correctly.